# Installed keyboard layout on Windows 10 but can't select it

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

It shows up in the keyboard list in

region & language -> russian -> options:

[image]

but not in system tray keyboard layout selection list:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you "Press and hold the Windows key while you press the Space bar to change the language."?

Comment: Nothing happens. stays in english

Answer (score 0):

If the words I'm using are not accurate, it's because I can't change my UI language to English right away.

In the language settings, where you got when you clicked on "Russian", you should actually have three options on each language: "As Default", "Options", "Remove/Delete".

If you set Russian as default language, it will appear in the task bar as selectable language. It will stay there, even if you change back to English.

You may have to do this upon every system startup though, because this may be caused by some software installed on your PC. (At least, for me a specific software is the reason for this issue.)